# XSLT: Setting global variable to attribute value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

**General**
I'm trying to modify an XML that includes JavaScript. I want to add an extra top hierarchial level if the JavaScript is referencing one of the page top levels.

**Specifics**
I want to find the new top level (formName) and then add it to the scripts if they have assignments that start with a page top level (pageNames and subPageNames). I have tried to run this in XMLSpy, but I can't even populate variable formName. What is the best way of solving this?

My example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template>
  <subform name="formABC">
    <pageSet>
        <pageArea name="Page1">
            <subform>
                <field>
                    <event>
                        <script>this.rawValue = SubPageA.subhuvud.namn.rawValue;</script>
                    </event>
                </field>
                <field>
                    <event>
                        <script>this.rawValue = not_this.rawValue;</script>
                    </event>
                </field>
            </subform>
        </pageArea>
        <pageArea name="Page2">
            <field>
                <event>
                    <script>this.rawValue = SubPageK.subhuvud.namn.rawValue;</script>
                </event>
            </field>
            <area>
                <field>
                    <event>
                        <script>this.rawValue = Page1.subhuvud.namn.rawValue;</script>
                    </event>
                </field>
                <field>
                    <event>
                        <script>this.rawValue = other.rawValue;</script>
                    </event>
                </field>
            </area>
        </pageArea>
    </pageSet>
    <subform name="SubPageA">
    </subform>
    <subform name="SubPageK">
    </subform>
  </subform>
</template>
```

My current XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="formName"     select="/xdp:xdp/template/subform/@name"/>
<xsl:variable name="pageNames"    select="/xdp:xdp/template/subform/subform/@name"/>
<xsl:variable name="subPageNames" select="/xdp:xdp/template/subform/pageSet/pageArea/@name"/>
<xsl:variable name="allPageNames" select="concat($pageNames, $subPageNames)"/>

<!--    Identity rule.-->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--Rewite Javascript-->
<!--Insert formname in front of page that is first.-->
<xsl:template match="//script">
    <xsl:variable name="match" select="exsl:node-set($allPageNames)[contains(current(), .)]"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$match">                                                <!--this.rawValue = Page1.subhuvud.namn.rawValue;-->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., $match)"/>                <!--this.rawValue = -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$formName"/>                                  <!--formABC-->
            <xsl:value-of select="'.'"/>                                        <!--.-->
            <xsl:value-of select="$match"/>                                     <!--Page1-->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., $match)"/>                 <!--.subhuvud.namn.rawValue;-->
        </xsl:when>                                                             <!--this.rawValue = formABC.Page1.subhuvud.namn.rawValue;-->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output that I seek:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template>
 <subform name="formABC">
    <pageSet>
        <pageArea name="Page1">
            <subform>
                <field>
                    <event>
                        <script>this.rawValue = formABC.SubPageA.subhuvud.namn.rawValue;</script>
                    </event>
                </field>
                <field>
                    <event>
                        <script>this.rawValue = not_this.rawValue;</script>
                    </event>
                </field>
            </subform>
        </pageArea>
        <pageArea name="Page2">
            <field>
                <event>
                    <script>this.rawValue = formABC.SubPageK.subhuvud.namn.rawValue;</script>
                </event>
            </field>
            <area>
                <field>
                    <event>
                        <script>this.rawValue = formABC.Page1.subhuvud.namn.rawValue;</script>
                    </event>
                </field>
                <field>
                    <event>
                        <script>this.rawValue = other.rawValue;</script>
                    </event>
                </field>
            </area>
        </pageArea>
    </pageSet>
    <subform name="SubPageA">
    </subform>
    <subform name="SubPageK">
    </subform>
  </subform>
  </template>
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that the `select` expressions in your variable bindings assume that the root element will be an `<xdp:xdp>`, but that's not what it is in your example input.

Comment: Ooops, yes thats a remnant of the original XML structure before I simplified it for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to binding variables' values, I expand on my comment by pointing out that your `select` expressions rooted at `/xdp:xdp` will never match anything in your example input file, thus values of the associated variables will always be empty node sets.  You should be able to fix that (with respect to the example input) simply by removing that element:

```
<xsl:variable name="formName" select="/template/subform/@name"/>
```

Next, I observe that the mechanism by which you form the value for variable `allPageNames` cannot work because `concat()` requires *string* arguments, but you are trying to provide node sets.  Nor would converting the node sets to strings do the right thing, because

1. Converting a node set to a string gets you the string value of the *first* node (only)
2. You're trying to form an undelimited concatenation, from which you would be unable afterward to extract the original strings.
3. Where you actually use the value, you convert it to a node set, so wouldn't it be better to just generate the value as a node set in the first place?

XPath has a node-set union operator, `|`, which you can use in the expression  for this variable's value.  For example,

```
<xsl:variable name="pageNames"    select="/template/subform/subform/@name"/>
<xsl:variable name="subPageNames" select="/template/subform/pageSet/pageArea/@name"/>
<xsl:variable name="allPageNames" select="$pageNames | $subPageNames"/>
```

Now you don't need EXSL (for what you present in the question), because `allPageNames` is already a node set.

But that's not enough: you have a problem with variable `match` in the `script` template. The `select` expression in its assignment will not work, because `contains()` is another string function, and you are attempting to pass a node set to it.  Moreover, where it is inside the predicate, it will evaluate to the node being tested, *not*, as it appears you want, the `<script>` element being transformed.  In any case, the test you seem to be trying to perform is prone to false positives.

I suggest a different approach.  First, identify the name of the object you want to test.  This looks like this might be consistent with your objective as you describe it, when processed with the `script` element as the context node:

```
<xsl:variable name="topObject"
    select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat(substring-after(., '='), '.'), '.'))"/>
```

Having done that you can test whether the selected name is among those described by the `$allPageNames` node set via this test expression: `$allPageNames[. = $topObject]`.  Overall, the `script` template might look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="script">
  <!-- assumed: this element has text-only content -->
  <xsl:variable name="topObject"
      select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat(substring-after(., '='), '.'), '.'))"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$allPageNames[. = $topObject]">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., $topObject)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$formName"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$topObject"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., $topObject)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks for all the effort you put into explaining this! /Björn

Comment: What use is the concat() function doing? To my understanding it is appending a dot that is then removed by the substring-before().

Comment: @Björn, that's exactly what it is doing.  This is useful when the original string has no `'.'` in it.  If it were passed directly to `substring-before()` then the result would be an empty string, but this way it is instead the whole string.  When the starting string already contains a `'.'`, the overall result is the same as it would be without the `concat()`.